# Sum of the given series: $(1^2 - 1 + 1)(1!) + (2^2 - 2 + 1)(2!) + \cdots + (n^2 - n + 1)(n!) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

> Find the sum of the following series:
>   $$(1^2 - 1 + 1)(1!) + (2^2 - 2 + 1)(2!) + \cdots + (n^2 - n + 1)(n!) $$

---

I tried simplifying the $n^{th}$ term to use the method of telescoping to see if most of the terms get cancelled. But I couldn't simplify it in a way that was helpful. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\left(n^2-n+1\right)n!=(n+2)!-4(n+1)!+3n!$ This should telescope nicely.

Comment: Thanks! How can someone think of writing it in the above form? Like what did you think of so that you'll get a form that would telescope nicely?

Comment: Since we were multiplying by $n!$, we want to write $n^2-n+1$ as a combination of $1$, $n+1$, and $(n+2)(n+1)$, so that, after multiplying by $n!$, we would get a combination of $n!$, $(n+1)!$, and $(n+2)!$; that is, $n^2-n+1=(n+2)(n+1)-4(n+1)+3$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2-k+1)k!=\sum_{k=1}^n [(k+1)^2-3k]k!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)(k+1)!-\sum_{k=1}^n kk!-2\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=$$

$$=(n+1)(n+1)!-1-2\sum_{k=1}^n kk!$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1-1)k!=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)!-\sum_{k=1}^n k!=(n+1)!-1$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2-k+1)k!=(n+1)(n+1)!-1-2((n+1)!-1)=(n-1)(n+1)!+1$$

Comment: I did not understand the following: $(+1)(+1)!−1−2∑_{=1}^!$

Comment: The two sums telescope and we remain with that. It is just an intermediate step.